# Left outer joins in FetchXML with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm trying to do a left outer join in FetchXML with multiple conditions.

Here is the approximate SQL of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT incident.*, externalCheck.*
FROM incident
LEFT OUTER JOIN externalCheck 
  ON externalCheck.incidentId = incident.incidentId
  AND externalCheck.checkType = 1
  AND externalCheck.isLatest = 1;
```

NB: This should always return a 1:1 relationship since our business logic requires that there is only one *isLatest* for each *checkType*.

And here is my FetchXML:

```
<entity name="incident">
  <all-attributes />
  <link-entity name="externalCheck" from="incidentId" to="incidentId" link-type="outer">
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="checkType" operator="eq" value="1" />
      <condition attribute="isLatest" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <all-attributes />
  </link-entity>
</entity>
```

**The Problem**

The problem is that incident records where the right-hand side of the join are null (i.e. there is no *externalCheck* record) are not being returned, whereas in a left outer join I would expect that the incident record is still returned even if the right-hand side of the join is null.

What I suspect is that FetchXML is converting my filter to a WHERE clause, rather than adding the conditions to the ON clause.

**The Question**

Can anyone confirm what is happening, and a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is correct. But you can overcome from it somewhat.

Fetchxml is flexible & the below snippet will give the  results for left outer join with multiple clause.

```
<entity name="incident">
  <all-attributes />
  <link-entity name="externalCheck" alias="ext" from="incidentId" to="incidentId" link-type="outer">
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="checkType" operator="eq" value="1" />
      <condition attribute="isLatest" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
  </link-entity>
   <filter>
    <condition entityname="ext" attribute="externalCheckid" operator= "null" />
   </filter>
</entity>
```

The real problem is with `externalCheck.*`, you cannot get the related entity attributes. Have to remove the `<all-attributes />` from `link-entity` node.

[Read more](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2016/02/fetchxml-left-outer-joins-with-multiple-on-clauses.html)

Comment: Hi Arun. Thanks for your answer. I've tried various versions of your XML, but I keep getting an error that "entityname" is not a valid attribute for the condition. Without the entityname, the fetch will run, but it makes no difference to the number of rows returned.

Comment: Looks like it should work, but XrmToolBox is complaining about that attribute."The entityname attribute is not a valid attribute for link-entity." This despite the fact that I've added the attribute on the condition node. Weird.

Comment: @MarkMicallef forget the xrmtoolbox, is it executing in your code & fetch results ?